# PSQL case insensitive INDEX lower() doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, indexing, constraints, case-insensitive

Currently, I am working on a making data in a column, "filename", to be case insensitive when they are searched or compared. 
In the **files** DB, I have files with names SAMPLE.txt and sAMple.Txt. ...
And I want to get all this files with the same name when I execute

```
SELECT * from files where filename='sample.txt'
```

So, I made an index by this command...

```
CREATE INDEX files_lower_fnames_idx ON files ((lower(filename)));
```

It was successfully created. 
But upon executing...

```
SELECT * from files where filename='sample.txt'
```

it still returned 0 rows.

Am I missing something?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: surely you just need SELECT * from files where lower(filename) ='sample.txt'

Comment: alternatively you can set the table collation to be case insensitive accent sensitive then SAmPle.Txt would be the same as sample.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it still returned 0 rows.

Creating an index has *no effect* on the outcome of a query, only the *performance* of the query. If it returned 0 rows before index creation, it should after too.

I can't say for sure *why* it's returning 0 rows, since you haven't shown the data in the table. But if it's as you describe then

```
SELECT * from files where filename='sample.txt'
```

would not match it. You need either a `citext` column, or to do a case insensitive query like

```
SELECT * from files where lower(filename)='sample.txt'
```

This query should be able to use the index you created to run faster.

Comment: Understood. Thank you! :)